# How can node.js process large-capacity Excel files separately?

Tags: node.js

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

There is a problem in creating applications through electron and Exceljs.

I want to read the Excel file and show it to user in the html table. The problem is that it deals with xlsx files with a very large number of rows.
So I want to show the progress to the user as follows.
ex) 5/10000. (Read row / Total number of rows)

Also, if possible, I would like to return the data in the form of json or html whenever I read it. (If this is impossible, I'd like to indicate that it's loading until it's finished)

```
const filePath = "/Users/caglia/Documents/test.xlsx"
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs')

async function loadExcelFile(filePath) {
  let start = new Date();
  console.log('start :', Date.now())

  const sheetData = []

  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook()
  await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath)
  const worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0] // first sheet 

  const options = {
    includeEmpty: true
  }

  await worksheet.eachRow(options, (row, rowNum) => {
    sheetData[rowNum] = []
    //console.log('rowNum', rowNum)

    row.eachCell(options, (cell, cellNum) => {
     sheetData[rowNum][cellNum] = {
        value: cell.value
      }
    })
  })

  let end = new Date();
  console.log('finish ', Date.now(), 'timediff', end - start);
}

loadExcelFile(filePath)
```

Comment: Your question's title and content do not match.

Comment: You may take a look at the [source code of `Worksheet`](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/index.d.ts#:~:text=export%20interface%20Worksheet) . You may find properties like `rowCount` useful

Comment: @RickyMo Ok.thanks! It would have been nice if I could read the number of rows without reading all the files, but the rowCount you told me is useful.